# How many storyboard in a Swift iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

in my iOS app I have to add some views for different functions.

In which case is good add a new view in the same storyboard, or in which case is better to create a new storyboard and to add the views in the new one?

Thank all! I have searched in some discussions, but the only answer was related only to the data change between views. But my question is related to the "best practice", to the best way to develop.

Thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use multiple storyboards (instead of one large storyboard) because:

- it is version control friendly
- you can organize your code into seperate modules

Having said that, if your app is a tiny one with only a few views, there is no need to overthink this problem -- just do whatever is convenient.

Comment: Thank Jak! So, if I correct understood:

1) If I have 7 views for (i.e.) selling area, 10 for customer management, 8 for products, I have to manage in 3 storyboard, and create a link between different storyboard, so I can better organize my code and my functions
2) But if I have only 4 views, I can manage all in one storyboard
3) Obviously, if I think in the future to expand my app, it is a good idea use more than one storyboard at the beginning. Is all correct? Thk (and 4, only a question: why is version control friendly? Is not the same v.c.f., only one storyboard?)

Comment: @Archimede Yes you understand correctly. Using multiple storyboards are considered best practices by many developers who use storyboards seriously. And 4, when I say version control friendly I mean merge conflicts when more than one developer is working on the same project. Merging storyboards is not an easy task. Using more than one storyboard means the possibility of merge conflicts are smaller.

Comment: Thank, the question is solved!